# Automate The Boring Stuff With Python: Chapter 4 Practice Project II

Tags: python

I've been thru d comments for an almost similar question but there's no solution to solve my little problem.

My code seems to work but i still get 'IndexError: List index out of range'.

This is my code:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',],\
['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.',],\
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.',],\
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.',],\
['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O',],\
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.',],\
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.',],\
['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.',],\
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',]]
def fish():
    m = 0
    n = 0
    while m != len(grid):
        print (grid[m][n] + \
        grid[m+1][n] + \
        grid[m+2][n] + \
        grid[m+3][n] + \
        grid[m+4][n] + \
        grid[m+5][n] + \
        grid[m+6][n] + \
        grid[m+7][n] + \
        grid[m+8][n])
        n = n+1
fish()
```

Comment: Post the full error message.

Comment: You are incrementing n each time through but the condition for your while loop uses `m != len(grid)`. Is `n != len(grid)` what you are looking for?

Comment: You probably want `while n != len(grid): ` Or you should increment `m`. Either way, this is a simple typo

Comment: Full error message:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\My Computer\...project C4.py", line 25, in <module>
            fish()
        File "C:\Users\My Computer\...project C4.py", line 25, in fish
            grid[m+7][n] + \
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 3):

Might I suggest an alternative answer

```
def fish():
    for line in zip(*grid):
        print(''.join(line))
```

Prints

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop will never terminate because your `m` value is never updated, you only update your `n` value.

This will cause your loop to run forever, eventually giving you an `IndexError` when it reaches too large a value for `n`.

If you know that there are going to be exactly 8 rows in your grid, then you should probably make it so that your `while` loop checks the value of `n` not `m` and checks against the length of one of the rows (like `grid[0]`) like this:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',],\
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.',],\
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.',],\
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.',],\
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O',],\
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.',],\
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.',],\
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.',],\
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',]]

def fish():
    m = 0
    n = 0
    while n < len(grid[0]):
        print (grid[m][n] + \
        grid[m+1][n] + \
        grid[m+2][n] + \
        grid[m+3][n] + \
        grid[m+4][n] + \
        grid[m+5][n] + \
        grid[m+6][n] + \
        grid[m+7][n] + \
        grid[m+8][n])
        n = n+1
fish()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty much new to programming and my answer is this:

It also gives the correct result but for sure not the best way to solve the problem, but still, an alternative one.

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]



for x in range(len(grid)):
    for y in range(len(grid)):
        try:
            if y == len(grid)-1:
                print(grid[y][x])

            else:
                print(grid[y][x], end='')
        except IndexError:
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

#### My solution for the problem :-

I followed the hint and traversed the matrix (list matrix in this case) column-wise. So `[0][0],[1][0],[2][0]` and so on. Then I printed this traversed column as the first row for the final result (as required in the problem). Iterated in the same manner for other columns also.

Furthermore, just for fun ,I also made the final result as a nested list so that it is just like input.

Note : Used the knowledge till chapter 4 only. There are other advanced methods to solve this problem as posted by other people.

#### The Code

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

        #Initial Matrix
        for row in grid:
            print (row)

        #Creating the pattern
        result=[]
        for x in range(len(grid[0])):
            strResult= ''
            for y in range(len(grid)):
                  #Printing the pattern in non-list form
                  print(grid[y][x],end='') 
                  strResult = strResult + str(grid[y][x]);
            result.append(list(strResult))
            print()

        #Printing the pattern in list form
        for row in result:
            print (row)
```

#### Prints

```
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.']
['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.']
['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']


..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....


['.', '.', 'O', 'O', '.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.']
['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.']
['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.']
['.', '.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', 'O', '.', '.', '.', '.']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def love(x):
while x != len(grid[0]):
    for y in range (len(grid)):
        print(grid[y][x],end="")
    print()
    x+=1
grid=[['.','.','.','.','.','.'],
  ['.','0','0','.','.','.'],
  ['0','0','0','0','.','.'],
  ['0','0','0','0','0','.'],
  ['.','0','0','0','0','0'],
  ['0','0','0','0','0','.'],
  ['0','0','0','0','.','.'],
  ['.','0','0','.','.','.'],
  ['.','.','.','.','.','.']]
x=0
love(x)


..00.00..
.0000000.
.0000000.
..00000..
...000...
....0....
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to make this work for any given length of lists.
The task though was to make it work with the particular list in a list in the practice project. This code uses only the content taught in the book until chapter 4 (because I'm just starting to code and only know this book until here):

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
for x in range(0,6):
    print(end='\n')
    for y in range(0,9):
        print(grid[y][x],end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to make the code work for any size of array, maybe have a look at this solution:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'], 
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

x = 0
y = 0

while x < len(grid[0]):           #Determine number of lists in list
  while y < len(grid):            #Determine number of lists
    print(grid[y][x], end='')     #Print each element on line
    y += 1                        #Up Y by one each cycle until while stops
  print('\n')                     #Move to a new line
  x += 1                          #Increase x by one and reset Y, restarts 
  y = 0                           #second while loop until both run out.
```

Answer (score 0):

The below seems to work (but double check it you experts), and also only uses tools taught in ch 1-4. My maiden post BTW.

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
    ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

n = 0  #index for arbitrary sub-list since all sub-lists are same length 
for i in range(len(grid[n])):  # upper-level loop with i as the "item-level" variable 
    for t in range(len(grid)-1):  # lower-level loop with t as sub-list level variable 
        print(grid[t][i],end='')  # on same line, print one item (i) from each sub-list (t) except for last sub-list 
    print(grid[t][-1])  # after the above lower-level loop finishes (prints eight items), print 9th and final item (i) from sub-list (t), then create new line before continuing upper-level loop for next value of t.
```

Do let me know if I'm not seeing a condition in which this will break down.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make it universal:

```
# character picture grid -- ascii art

grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
        ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

# size of grid may vary, so len(grid) is used

def myfish():
    for y in range(len(grid[0])):      # length of first element of list
        for x in range(len(grid)):     # length of list
            print(grid[x][y], end='')
        print('\n')

myfish()
```

I'm not sure, so please tell me if the code may break down in some case...

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 0 
y = 0
while y < len(grid[x]):
for x in range(len(grid)):
        print(grid[x][y], end='')
print()
y +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was studying and came up with this idea:

```
# Heart with grid project
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

spam = 0
eggs = 0
bacon = ''

for eggs in range (0,6): #as the book hints we should go row by row so that's why this first 'for'
    for spam in range (0,9):
        bacon += '{}  '.format(grid[spam][eggs]) # Here we swap rows with columns because we want to transpose it; we start by increasing the first value,that's why we use 'spam' first and 'eggs' on the second '[]' and then we proced to the next line.
    print('{}'.format(bacon)) # Here we print the line created for 'bacon'
    bacon = '' #then we need to reset this because otherwise it will stack multiple 'bacons' together
print('There is our pretty heart!')
```

prints:

```
.  .  O  O  .  O  O  .  .  
.  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  .  
.  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  .  
.  .  O  O  O  O  O  .  .  
.  .  .  O  O  O  .  .  .  
.  .  .  .  O  .  .  .  .  
There is our pretty heart!
```

Answer (score 0):

just transverse the matrix:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

for f in range(len(grid[0:6])):
    for c in range(len(grid[0:9])):
        print(grid[c][f],end=' ')
    print(' ')

output:
. . O O . O O . .  
. O O O O O O O .  
. O O O O O O O .  
. . O O O O O . .  
. . . O O O . . .  
. . . . O . . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Style # to be able to add color
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else clear) # to clear the screen

grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

for i in range(len(grid[0])):
    for j in range(len(grid)):
        if grid[j][i] == '.': # to decide whether to print or not
            print(' ', end='  ') # to not print .
        else:
            print(Fore.RED + grid[j][i], end='  ') # to print O in red
    print()
print(Style.RESET_ALL) # to reset the colors and style
```

Comment: Please add sone description so that feature readers can understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is did.

```
grid =[
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

print('Old Grid:')

for i in range(0,len(grid)):
    for j in range(0,len(grid[i])):
        if j==0:
            print(grid[i][j],'  ', end='')
        elif j%(len(grid[i])-1)!=0:
            print(grid[i][j],'  ', end='')
        else:
            print(grid[i][j],'  ')

print('new Grid:')

for y in range(0,len(grid[1])):
    for x in range(0,len(grid)):
        if x==0:
            print(grid[x][y],' ', end='')
        elif x%(len(grid)-1)!=0:
            print(grid[x][y],' ',end='')
        else:
            print(grid[x][y],' ')
```

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mREa9.png)

Answer (score -2):

add an m+1 after the n+1 and you should be good to go